# Add a circle as a selection indicator above UITabbarItem in Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to add a selection indicator to a UITabbarItem in Swift, like the following image.

[image]

I tried to code below but I cannot add the circle above the UITabBar.

On viewDidLoad:

```
 let tabBar = self.tabBarController!.tabBar
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().createSelectionIndicator(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.width/CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count), tabBar.frame.height), lineWidth: 8.0)
```

```
extension UIImage {
    func createSelectionIndicator(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        let innerRect = CGRect(x: (size.width/2) - lineWidth/2,
                                    y: -2,
                                    width: lineWidth,
                                    height: lineWidth)

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerRect, cornerRadius: lineWidth/2)
        path.fill()

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
     }
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use different image with circle for selected state.
If you use SVG image with custom size, it will be better.
You can change it from storyboard.

[image: check the storyboard screenshot.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But unfortunately, I have to follow the design...